# Send data and submit form to different website and get result

Tags: html, forms, cross-server

Let's say I have a text `<input>`.

Is there any way to:

- send the text in the input to a separate website with a login screen
- fill in the login details

OR

- fill in a search box on the site
- submit the search
- get search results

Assuming this is possible, can I retrieve the result? Can I display the results somehow in an `<iframe>` or something like that?

Comment: use `cURL` to do that.

Comment: _"Is there any way to programmatically send the text in the input to a separate website"_ What is "website" ?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, if you know which form the data goes to and what data (`GET` or `POST` variables), then you might be able to send data directly to that form via PHP. <strike>AFAIK, I don't think this is possible because of anti-cross-server safety measures except with certain libraries.</strike>

**EDIT**

- With JS/jQuery and AJAX, this is not possible because of the ["Same Origin Policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
- In PHP, you **can** do this, using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

For the second part, the "results" (i.e., a search page, or an account/logged in/welcome page) should be a webpage that you can easily put in an `<iframe>` as normal. If you don't know how to use an `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="PAGE_URL">Your browser doesn't support iframe.</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I am OK with using iframes so hopefully when I learn about the cURL a bit more I can work it out. Any working examples of cURL in action? for a beginner that I can dissect and understand